# Truncated result returned by JOIN

Tags: linux, text-processing, join

I'm using join command under linux, but the results vary between different machines.
I have two simple files:

```
cat 1.txt  
a aaa,0.2
b bbb,0.3
c ccc,0.5

cat 2.txt
a aaa,0.2
b bbb,0.3
c ccc,0.6
```

I'm running the following command

```
join -a 1 -1 1 -2 1 -t "," -o 1.1' '1.2' '2.2 <(cat 1.txt| sort -t ",") <(cat 2.txt| sort -t ",")
```

Result on machine 1:

```
,0.2a,0.2
,0.3b,0.3
,0.6c,0.5

join --version
join (GNU coreutils) 8.13

locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Result on machine 2:

```
a aaa,0.2,0.2
b bbb,0.3,0.3
c ccc,0.5,0.6

join --version
join (GNU coreutils) 5.97

locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Clearly, the result on the first machine is wrong. It's been truncated. I've tried to use different locale settings but had no success.

Comment: looks like the file with the odd results has DOS-style `\r\n` line endings. What does `cat -v a.txt b.txt` show?

Comment: ^M is a carriage return, also known as the `\r` escape sequence. Since linux uses only newline as the line ending, the carriage return is still present as the last character of the line. Printing a carriage return has the effect of moving the cursor back to position 0 of the line, and characters that were previously printed are overwritten.

Comment: Hi Glenn, thank you very much! it works! what's the reason for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your files with `dos2unix`, or if that's not installed:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' {1,2}.txt
```